# Add-Leaf function "hanging", custom BST Class in C++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

This problem is a little more complicated than previous ones I've brought here, so I'll try to be very explicit about what I've narrowed it down to.

I'm writing a Binary Search Tree data class in C++ that functions like a standard BST except that it stores duplicates of Odd numbers using a "count" field in the BST node.

I've written a test driver to test the member functions of the class and have run into an error that I cannot seem to solve. When I attempt to add a set number of random integers to a BST object none of them  seem to make it into the tree. To check the contents I use a printInOrder function that I have confirmed works properly so I know the problem isn't there.

For starters, I'll post the addLeaf, printInOrder, and createLeaf functions, and the small block of code where I call them in my driver file.

```
bool fixedDupBST::addLeaf(int key)
{   
    if(root == nullptr){
        root = createLeaf(key);
        assert(root != nullptr);
    }
    else {
        node *prev = nullptr;
        node *scanPtr = root;
        bool right, dupe = false;
        while(scanPtr != nullptr) {
            prev = scanPtr;
            if(key < scanPtr->key) {
                scanPtr = scanPtr->left;
                right = false;
            }
            else if (key == scanPtr->key) {
                if (scanPtr->keyCount >= 1)
                    dupe = true;
                else{
                    dupe = false;
                    scanPtr = nullptr;
                }
            }
            else {
                scanPtr = scanPtr->right;
                right = true;
            }
        }
        if (dupe)
            prev->keyCount++;
        else if (!dupe)
            return false;
        else if (right) {
            prev->right = createLeaf(key);
            assert(prev->right != nullptr);
        }
        else {
            prev->left = createLeaf(key);
            assert(prev->left != nullptr);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

fixedDupBST::node* fixedDupBST::createLeaf(int key)
{
    node* newNode = new node;
    assert(newNode != nullptr);
    newNode->key = key;
    newNode->left = nullptr;
    newNode->right = nullptr;
    if (key % 2 != 0)
        newNode->keyCount = 1;
    else
        newNode->keyCount = 0;
    return newNode;
}

void fixedDupBST::printInOrder()
{
    printInOrderPr(root);
}
void fixedDupBST::printInOrderPr(node* Ptr)
{
    if(root != nullptr) {
        if(Ptr->left != nullptr){
            printInOrderPr(Ptr->left);
        }
        cout << Ptr->key << ' ';
        if(Ptr->right != nullptr) {
            printInOrderPr(Ptr->right);
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "The tree is empty" << endl;
    }

    return;
}

void testInsert(fixedDupBST &BST)
{
    int temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < TEST_PARAM; i++) {
        temp = randNum();
        BST.addLeaf(temp);
    }
    BST.printInOrder();
    return;
}
```

The problem I'm getting is that when I call printInOrder() it always gives "The tree is empty". At first I thought it might be a problem with how I was passing parameters in the class member functions (pass by references vs pass by value) but that didn't provide any solutions. If there are any problems at all with the rest of the function it doesn't seem to matter because root never gets assigned to that first node, (hence why print in order just says "the tree is empty".

I need a second set of eyes on this; thanks in advanced for you help, and let me know if I can rephrase my question or provide more information to help make the situation clearer.

EDIT: R Sahu had the error correct, but his answer is a little off. I realized that a bool wouldn't work cleanly for what I was trying to do because there are actually 3 cases:
The number is a duplicate and is odd,
the number is a duplicate and is even
and the number is NOT a duplicate.

The problem stemmed from the fact that the quit condition for the while loop was scanPtr being null, and the if/else-if statement at the end had no way of knowing if it was null because it reached the end of a subtree and was ready to insert, or if I had manually set it to null upon finding a duplicate in order to break the loop appropriately.

Here is the solution I came up with.

```
bool fixedDupBST::addLeaf(int key)
{   
    if(root == nullptr){
        root = createLeaf(key);
        assert(root != nullptr);
    }
    else {
        node *prev = nullptr;
        node *scanPtr = root;
        bool right;
        int dupe = 0;  // switch variable
        while(scanPtr != nullptr) {
            prev = scanPtr;
            if(key < scanPtr->key) {
                scanPtr = scanPtr->left;
                right = false;
            }
            else if (key == scanPtr->key) {
                if (key % 2 != 0) {
                    dupe = 1;
                    scanPtr = nullptr;
                }
                else{
                    dupe = 2;
                    scanPtr = nullptr;
                }
            }
            else {
                scanPtr = scanPtr->right;
                right = true;
            }
        }
        if (dupe == 2)
            return false;

        if (dupe == 1)
            prev->keyCount++;
        else if (right) {
            prev->right = createLeaf(key);
            assert(prev->right != nullptr);
        }
        else {
            prev->left = createLeaf(key);
            assert(prev->left != nullptr);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Everything works appropriately now.

Comment: I don't see why this code wouldn't work. Try going in with debugger? Make particular note of the value of `this` in all methods. Reduce your test to just inserting one node for starters.

Comment: It will add a single node. I just called BST.addLeaf() from main(). It will only add the first node though, I tried calling it manually from main with several hard-coded values and only the first int added gets printed by printInOrder. So it's either not getting added or it's not being printed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a logic error in this block.

```
    if (dupe)
        prev->keyCount++;
    else if (!dupe)    // This is pointless
                       // dupe is either true or false.
                       // Your code will never get to the next "else if"
        return false;
    else if (right) {
        prev->right = createLeaf(key);
        assert(prev->right != nullptr);
    }
    else {
        prev->left = createLeaf(key);
        assert(prev->left != nullptr);
    }
```

What you need is:

```
    if (dupe) {
        prev->keyCount++;
        return false;   // I think you want to return false here but I am not sure
    }
    else if (right) {
        prev->right = createLeaf(key);
        assert(prev->right != nullptr);
    }
    else {
        prev->left = createLeaf(key);
        assert(prev->left != nullptr);
    }
```

Comment: This seems to have solved it but I'll run a couple quick tests just to be sure. That line was a vestigial bit from a previous draft, I should document the changes I make more carefully :)

Answer (score 0):

R Sahu had the error correct, but his answer is a little off. I realized that a bool wouldn't work cleanly for what I was trying to do because there are actually 3 cases:
1: The number is a duplicate and is odd.
2: the number is a duplicate and is even.
3: the number is NOT a duplicate.

The problem stemmed from the fact that the quit condition for the while loop was scanPtr being null, and the if/else-if statement at the end had no way of knowing if it was null because it reached the end of a subtree and was ready to insert, or if I had manually set it to null upon finding a duplicate in order to break the loop appropriately.

Here is the solution I came up with.

```
bool fixedDupBST::addLeaf(int key)
{   
    if(root == nullptr){
        root = createLeaf(key);
        assert(root != nullptr);
    }
    else {
        node *prev = nullptr;
        node *scanPtr = root;
        bool right;
        int dupe = 0;  // switch variable
        while(scanPtr != nullptr) {
            prev = scanPtr;
            if(key < scanPtr->key) {
                scanPtr = scanPtr->left;
                right = false;
            }
            else if (key == scanPtr->key) {
                if (key % 2 != 0) {
                    dupe = 1;
                    scanPtr = nullptr;
                }
                else{
                    dupe = 2;
                    scanPtr = nullptr;
                }
            }
            else {
                scanPtr = scanPtr->right;
                right = true;
            }
        }
        if (dupe == 2)
            return false;

        if (dupe == 1)
            prev->keyCount++;
        else if (right) {
            prev->right = createLeaf(key);
            assert(prev->right != nullptr);
        }
        else {
            prev->left = createLeaf(key);
            assert(prev->left != nullptr);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Everything works appropriately now.